# NPE when a TabActivity is started

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have an activity that is formed of 2 tabs. The problem is, when I have this code:

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);`

I am getting the following exception:

```
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-14 01:06:39.520: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(588):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

However, if I change the second tab to be displayed by default (I have only 2 tabs), as in:

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);`

everything is displayed correctly **and** I am able to switch between the tabs as well. This tells me that the tabs are configured correctly somehow, but then, why this behavior ?

Comment: we probably need to see your tab setup code.

Comment: are you sure the tabhost index starts at 0 ?

Comment: I realized what I was doing wrong: the Tab mechanism was working ok, it was a ListActivity implemented for the first tab that was causing the NPE.

Comment: I have same problem, whenever i run my code in android device then it works fine but when i run this in emulator then it creates problem. Please suggest me what should do for this. Thank you in andvance.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was doing wrong: the Tab mechanism was working ok, it was a ListActivity implemented for the first tab that was causing the NPE.